# Fakes does not support framework .net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-fakes

When trying to create ms-fakes assembly, I get this. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, MS Fakes assembly type works only with windows project type only.